# Android SDK Live Agent Crash Issues Headers.java line 268 okhttp3.Headers.checkValue

Tags: salesforce1-app

We received a lot crash report

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: value for name x-liveagent-session-key == null
>   at okhttp3.Headers.checkValue(Headers.java:268)
>   at okhttp3.Headers$Builder.add(Headers.java:312)
>   at okhttp3.Request$Builder.addHeader(Request.java:196)
>   at com.salesforce.android.service.common.http.okhttp.SalesforceOkHttpRequest$Builder.addHeader(SalesforceOkHttpRequest.java:127)
>   at com.salesforce.android.service.common.liveagentclient.request.MessagesRequest.build(MessagesRequest.java:74)
>   at com.salesforce.android.service.common.liveagentclient.LiveAgentClient.createRequest(LiveAgentClient.java:239)
>   at com.salesforce.android.service.common.liveagentclient.LiveAgentClient.sendAndGetResponse(LiveAgentClient.java:225)
>   at com.salesforce.android.service.common.liveagentclient.LiveAgentClient.sendAndGetResponse(LiveAgentClient.java:211)
>   at com.salesforce.android.service.common.liveagentclient.handler.MessagesHandler.requestMessages(MessagesHandler.java:129)
>   at com.salesforce.android.service.common.liveagentclient.handler.MessagesHandler.onSessionStateChanged(MessagesHandler.java:175)
>   at com.salesforce.android.service.common.liveagentclient.SessionListenerNotifier.onSessionStateChanged(SessionListenerNotifier.java:68)
>   at com.salesforce.android.service.common.liveagentclient.LiveAgentSession.onStateChanged(LiveAgentSession.java:212)
>   at com.salesforce.android.service.common.liveagentclient.LiveAgentSession.onStateChanged(LiveAgentSession.java:62)
>   at com.salesforce.android.service.common.utilities.lifecycle.LifecycleEvaluator.stateChanged(LifecycleEvaluator.java:305)
>   at com.salesforce.android.service.common.utilities.lifecycle.LifecycleStateWatcher$1.run(LifecycleStateWatcher.java:79)
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)

Comment: What's your question exactly. It doesn't seem like there's a lot we can do with this information.

Comment: @Adrian Larson, we received a lot crash fatal report on this error, what we found out is actually is from Salesforce SDK library okhttp issues. We wondering any thing to prevent this crash happen again.